# how to use one component render many html fragment in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a button there, when I click this button, i want render a `div` and append it to `body`.

and when I click this button again, a new `div` be rendered.

I want: **How many times I click the button, how many `div` be render.**

The follow code can only render one `div`: ( jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pw4yq/ )

```
var $tool = document.getElementById('tool');
var $main = document.getElementById('main');

var partBox = React.createClass({displayName: 'partBox',
    render: function(){
        return (
            React.DOM.div({className:"box"}, "HELLO! ", this.props.ts)
        )
    }
});

var createBoxBtn = React.createClass({displayName: 'createBoxBtn',

    createBox: function(){
        var timeStamp = new Date().getTime();
        React.renderComponent(partBox( {ts:timeStamp} ), $main);
    },

    render: function(){
        return (
            React.DOM.button( {onClick:this.createBox}, "createBox")
        )
    }
});

React.renderComponent(createBoxBtn(null ), $tool);
```

Comment: please share jsfiddle

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar http://jsfiddle.net/pw4yq/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your app should be data driven, meaning the state of your app is kept outside the DOM. In your example, you are essentially keeping a list of Date objects. Put that into a state that you can modify, and render a box for each Date object you have created:

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pw4yq/6/

```
var $main = document.getElementById('main');

var partBox = React.createClass({displayName: 'partBox',
    render: function(){
        return (
            React.DOM.div({className:"box"}, "HELLO! ", this.props.ts)
        )
    }
});

var createBoxBtn = React.createClass({displayName: 'createBoxBtn',

    createBox: function(){
        var timeStamp = new Date().getTime();
        this.props.onClick({ts: timeStamp});
    },

    render: function(){
        return (
            React.DOM.button({onClick: this.createBox}, "createBox")
        )
    }
});

var app = React.createClass({
    displayName: "app",

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            partBoxes: []
        };
    },

    createBox: function(partBox) {
        this.state.partBoxes.push(partBox);
        this.forceUpdate();
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            React.DOM.div(null,
                createBoxBtn({onClick: this.createBox}),
                this.state.partBoxes.map(function(pb) {
                    return partBox({key: pb.ts, ts: pb.ts});
                })
            )
        );
    }
});


React.renderComponent(app(null), $main);
```